# Compress image_tag in one

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nivo-slider

I was wondering is there a method to compress all image_tag picture tags in one? I am using Nivo slider in header and I don't want to write all image tags in my layout page, so is there any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a subdirectory, or use some naming convention that can be found by `Dir.glob`.

You can then map the resulting collection to `image_tag`s and render the collection.